# Using JSON to write an array of hashes to a file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, hashmap

Currently I am doing this:

```
badLinks = Array.new
badLinksFile = File.new(arrayFilePath + 'badLinks.txt', 'w+')
badLinksFile.puts badLinks.to_json
```

The array `badLinks` contains the hashes and is:

```
brokenLink = Hash.new
brokenLink[:onPage] = @lastPage
brokenLink[:link] = @nextPage
badLinks.push(brokenLink)
```

When I look at the file it is empty. Should this work?

Comment: What is `badLinksFile` and `badLinks`? A file and an array respectively? Show them in your code please, along with how you open `badLinksFile`.

Comment: @theTinMan does that edit make more sense?

Answer (score 7):

A couple things to check:

```
badLinksFile = File.new(arrayFilePath + 'badLinks.txt', 'w+')
```

should probably be `'w'` instead of '`w+`'. From the IO documentation:

```
  "w"  |  Write-only, truncates existing file
       |  to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
  -----+--------------------------------------------------------
  "w+" |  Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
       |  or creates a new file for reading and writing.
```

I'd write the code more like this:

```
bad_links = []

brokenLink = {
  :onPage => @lastPage,
  :link => @nextPage
}

bad_links << brokenLink

File.write(arrayFilePath + 'badLinks.txt', bad_links.to_json)
```

That's not tested, but it makes more sense, and is idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: I you helped me before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904131/testing-links-in-a-web-app/14904883#14904883).  This is the same project.  I am trying to record a list of URLs visited, Broken links found, URL's found in que to be checked.  With my current program I need to read a file at the beginning, and for every 100 links rewrite the set of files.

Comment: Cool. Glad I was able to help. I'm curious why you are writing JSON to a file? Generally, when we're dealing with a record of the connections that succeed/fail, we use a database. The schema is up to you, but we can sure help you figure out how to build it. A database is *MUCH* better than a file on disk for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions.  Point me at a good place to start.  The reason I started with json is it seemed simple to use.

Comment: mySQL?  I have no experience with databases.  Can you help me out with a starting point?

Comment: Look at [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html), and experiment with SQLite. It's a good starting point. Both the README and Cheat Sheet are chock-full of information.