# How would I access a key from a hash that is within an array that is within a text file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to create an if/else statement that compares a user's input against all the name keys within a hash that's stored with a text file. How would I write this?

user_accts is the array.

Update of full if/else statement:

elsif choice == "2"
        puts "====== NEW CUSTOMER ======"
        puts "Choose a username:"
        prompt; login_name = gets.chomp

```
    #file.open("cust_accts.txt", "r")

    #if @user_accts.map { |acct| acct["name"]}.include?(login_name)
    if @user_accts.any? {|acct| acct["name"] == login_name }
        puts "Sorry, that username has already been taken" 
    elsif   
        puts "Choose a password:"
        prompt; login_password = gets.chomp

        user_accts << create_account(login_name, login_password)
        File.open("cust_accts.txt", "a") { |file| file.puts(user_accts)}            
    end
```

original if/else statement:

```
if login_name == #??? @user_accts.has_key?(login_name) ???
            puts "Sorry, that username has already been taken" 
        elsif   
            puts "Choose a password:"
            prompt; login_password = gets.chomp

            user_accts << create_account(login_name, login_password)
            File.open("cust_accts.txt", "a") { |file| file.puts(user_accts)}            
        end
```

This is exactly what is inputted to the cust_accts.txt file using this command:

**user_accts << create_account(login_name, login_password)**

**File.open("cust_accts.txt", "a") { |file| file.puts(user_accts)}**

cust_accts.txt

```
{"name"=>"Tom", "password"=>"popcorn", "balance"=>0}
{"name"=>"Avril", "password"=>"chain", "balance"=>0}
```

Comment: what does `@user_accts` contain? How does it look like?

Comment: Is user_accts an Array or a Hash?

Comment: @user_accts is an array that holds a hash

Comment: Are you able to parse your text file into a ruby object?  Did you create this text file or are you depending on someone else for this?

Comment: It was a text file that I created. Does it need to have this part within the text file? --> @user_accts =

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what your starting point is.

Assuming you have parsed your text file into `@user_accts`, so you have:

```
@user_accts = [{"name"=>"Tom", "password"=>"popcorn", "balance"=>0},
               {"name"=>"Avril", "password"=>"chain", "balance"=>0}]
```

Then you would want to do:

```
if @user_accts.map {|acct| acct["name"]}.include?(login_name)
  puts "Sorry, that username has already been taken"
else
  # ...
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Does it know that it has to access the text file first before retrieving the information?

Answer (score 0):

```
@user_accts = [{"name"=>"Tom", "password"=>"popcorn", "balance"=>0},
               {"name"=>"Avril", "password"=>"chain", "balance"=>0}]


if @user_accts.any? {|acct| acct["name"] == "Tom" }
  puts "Sorry, that username has already been taken"
else
  # ...
end

#=> Sorry, that username has already been taken
```

Comment: This solution didn't seem to work for me either. I see that you have:  

@user_accts = [{"name"=>"Tom", "password"=>"popcorn", "balance"=>0},
               {"name"=>"Avril", "password"=>"chain", "balance"=>0}]  My text file only has this part: [{"name"=>"Tom", "password"=>"popcorn", "balance"=>0},
               {"name"=>"Avril", "password"=>"chain", "balance"=>0}]

Comment: @LilithX did you run this code? why you think it will not work? how `@user_accrts` looks like of your one?

Comment: yes, I just ran the code and when I input a username that is listed within the text file, it just skips through the program and exits out.

Comment: @LilithX Did you read the text file content to the array `@user_accrts`? If so, show us the code of that array population.

Comment: Priti, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "read the text file content to the array @user_accrts"

Comment: You have to tell ruby to read each line of the file then tell it what to do with each line.  A.K.A. Parse the text file into ruby objects.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. I'll try to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is "How do I store objects in ruby for use at a later date?".  If you want to use a text file you need to put it into a format that can be parsed back into a ruby object like JSON or XML.  I would recommend using a database though.  A database like SQLite is very light weight and easy to learn. An advantage to using a DB is that when you use a DB you can set an option to have your results returned as a hash.

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988742/using-json-to-write-an-array-of-hashes-to-a-file), eventually decided that a DB was the way to go.

Comment: that may be a little more advanced for me right now. I'm new to ruby and still learning, but thank you, I will keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: If you don't want to use a DB then you need to write the file in JSON or XML then parse it into ruby objects.

Comment: @LilithX Is this learning exercise or is this a project that you need to get working?

Comment: Saving data to a txt file is not a good option.  if you want to see any of the examples work that have been given in this post plug them into IRB, both of them work.  The hard part of what you are trying to do is reading from a text file.  Ruby just sees this file as a string of ASCII characters, NOT ruby objects. You could use a DB, or write your objects in a ruby file "user_accts.rb" then require the file.  But I suspect what you are trying to do is not actually what you want.